# Integral of a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Today, while studying the rectifiability of a $C^1$ curve, I stumbled upon an integral and I don't know if I've interpreted it correctly. Here is the statement:

> Let $\phi : [a,b] \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^n, [a,b] \subseteq \Bbb{R}$. We are going to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the *components* of $\phi(t) = (x_1(t), ..., x_n(t))$ obtaining $$\phi(b) - \phi(a) = \int_{a}^{b} \phi'(t)dt $$

I was wondering what does $\int_{a}^{b} \phi'(t)dt$ mean. I suppose it is the same as $(\int_{a}^{b} x_1'(t)dt, \int_{a}^{b} x_2'(t)dt,\dotsb,\int_{a}^{b} x_n'(t)dt)$ but I'm not sure.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are right,  remove also the norm,  it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @dmtri Thanks a lot. The norm was in the context of the proof of the theorem, but I'm going to remove it. Another question: the fact that the two are equal is by definition or a consequence of a theorem?

Comment: Welcome. By consequence of the fundamental theorem of integration fixed for this vector function

Comment: The integral of a vector function is by definition the vector of the integrals of it's componets.